# @import geolocator_apple: Module 'geolocator_apple' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

The app works fine on emulator, but when I try to build it with Xcode to run on a real device it shows this error:

[image]

I tried to type `pod install` in the iOS folder:

[image]
But it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it works fine when I open `Runner.xcworkspace` instead of `Runner.xcodeproj`. So just open it.